# Saving data, about closing the UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

for probably a day I can't figure out, I have a UI attached to canvas, on this UI I have text and 2 buttons, closing and play, on each button I have a certain button click, for example hidepanel, and loading another scene, the problem is that every time you restart the game, this window appears constantly, and I can not figure out how to save data that the player clicked one of the buttons, and after that this window would no longer be displayed, when you re-enter the game. I thought that PlayerPrefs would help me with this, since I used It to save the account, but the problem is that as I understand it, I need to save the object, and PlayerPrefs doesn't seem to do this,but only works with a string, a number, and a floating-point number. I read about serialization, but from all the examples I found, I understood how to save only the player's position :(

Below are my button click and photos of my dashboard

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{

    public ButtonTutorial tutorial;


   void Save()
    {

        PlayerData saveData = new PlayerData();
        saveData = tutorial.HidePanel();



        string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveData);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Tutorial", jsonData);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
```

Comment: You only to store the state, an int of 0 or 1. If you need to save more, then create a class containing all the needed info. Add the Serializable attribute so you can convert to json and store as a string in PlayerPrefs.

Comment: Please take a look, I edited the code in the post, am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Yes and no. PlayerData has to have the Serializable attribute. You convert to json and save ok. But you first create a new PlayerData and replace it with whatever HidePanel returns. I believe smg is not right there.